# How can I sort applications by cache size?

Tags: applications, cache

How can I sort applications by cache size?

I can sort applications by data size in *Settings → Apps storage*, but it doesn't take into account the cache size, which can sometimes be significant.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

I use Android 6.0 with an LG 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir) offers this feature. Install and launch that app, go to Applications, click the four horizontal line at the top, and choose Cache size under Sort By.

[image: IMG:]

Note: tapping on Cache Size causes my device to get stuck on "Please Wait", so this may or may not work with your device.